# Deployment of Azure Databricks access connector results in "unathorized"

Tags: azure

I want to create an Azure Databricks access connector in Azure Portal, but everytime I try it results in 403: unauthorized. I am the global administrator, the owner of the resource group it's created in and the owner of the databricks workspace in that same resource group. What am I missing?

The error of the deployment:
[image]

I'm an admin in the DB workspace:
[image]

I'm the global administrator:

[image]

I'm the owner of the resource group:

[image]

As well as owner of the databricks resource in the above resource group:
[image]

Comment: While adding role you are getting this error? it is correct for  to whom you are assigning role?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy Access connector through Azure portal by giving subscription and resource group details.

[image]

With System assigned managed identity on status it deployed successfully with out any authentication error:

[image]

In my case I am having contributor privileges to resource group and Databricks workspace. Regarding 403 authentication error as per [this](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009fEillSAC/user-not-authorized-error-when-trying-to-deploy-access-connector-on-azure) add the service principal to the list of service principals in the Account Console. To add service principle, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals).